# Не переключается table view controller на view controller при нажатии на ячейку таблицы

Tags: swift

Смотрел [видеоурок по этой теме](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLzwEsEDhMZlZ89oXBx3nO30I7xt84bnnV&v=S7nYjPtbNl0). У того кто записал его, разумеется, все получилось.
Может ли мне кто нибудь подробно объяснить, как сделать то, что я  хочу?

Comment: ссылку на урок, и свой код в `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` или как там происходит переключение (storyboard?)

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLzwEsEDhMZlZ89oXBx3nO30I7xt84bnnV&v=S7nYjPtbNl0

Comment: Реализация там какая то другая. Я пока что не силен в swift, поэтому очень прошу объяснить как можно подробнее

Comment: Подключаю я без всякого кода, в storyboard. Ну а весь что у меня есть, ничем не отличается от кода из урока

Comment: посмотрите видео с 22:30 до 23:30. убедитесь, что у вас это сделано. если не поможет скидывайте код, надо смотреть

Comment: Это я, конечно же, сделал. Поэтому и возникли вопросы

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/HQzHAX1undMpA  ссылка на проект

Comment: Проблема не решена. Попробуйте сделать у себя то что я прошу

Comment: сделал уже. все работает. ну давайте разбираться опять. в сториборде ячейке идентификатор поменяли, код из ответа скопировали?

Comment: Код скопировал, везде поставил cell

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо вам еще раз и простите за мою невнимательность

Comment: `UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: ident)` поменяли на `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ident)!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

две ошибки:

- идентификатор ячейки в программе должен быть тот же что и в сториборд. У вас в борде "1" в программе "cell". Предполагаю, что вы хотели сделать идентификатор для segue, но ввели не туда. Переменуйте в storyboard чтоб везде было "cell"
- создаваться ячейка должна через `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, и весь метод должен выглядеть так:

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
      let ident = "cell"
      var cell: UITableViewCell
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ident)!
      cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: recipes[indexPath.row].img)
      cell.textLabel?.text = recipes[indexPath.row].name
      return cell
  }
  ```

(в ролике используется более старая версия swift, не обязательно то, что написано там, будет работать на новой версии)

Comment: не стесняйтесь поставить галочку :)